# Which was the first experiment to demonstrate that current is the same as charge in motion?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, charge, history

I realized that I do not know the answer to this question because even in my first course in physics they presume that the student knows that charges are electrons and currents are moving electrons. But the electron is a modern concept— what experiments demonstrated that currents and charge were made of the same substance originally?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect

Comment: I think it will depend on the context of the answer you would be happy with. For example, would you accept the first electronic vacuum tube device? Or would you accept such things as the kite-and-key-in-a-thunderstorm?

Comment: @hyportnex are you suggesting that it was understood that current consisted of moving charges after Maxwell’s equations had all been written down?

Comment: @Dan I think I would accept anything that unified the electrical repulsion of triboelectrically charged materials with the current pushed by a voltaic pile

Comment: "current pushed by a voltaic pile" Detected by magnetic effects? I was going to suggest you try hsm.SE , but I can't find it there: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/search?q=current+electrostatic Maybe you can think of better search terms.

Comment: I think this belongs to history of science and mathematics https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the Hall effect proved that normal metallic conduction is carried by *negative* charges, the same kind as the cathode rays are in vacuum tubes.

Comment: @hyportnex thank you, that is a nice thing to know.